# STL std::remove_if compiler failure

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am unable to get std::remove_if to compile as you can see I chose an alternative hand crank method that works fine, the compiler errors are at the bottom of the listing after the code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

//
// Find the largest compound word composed
// of sub-words from a list.
//
// - read list from file. 
//
// Psuedo Code:
//
// 1. Read Next Word from File.
// 2. Search in list for word formed from word.
// 3. if Found in List
// 4.   if Found Compound is longer then Current Compound
// 5.     Replace
// 6.     Remove all strings less then Current Compound Length 
// 7. 
//

typedef std::set<std::string> StrSet;
typedef StrSet::iterator StrSetIter;


struct if_substr
{
    std::string m_word;
public:
    if_substr(const std::string& w) : m_word(w) { }

    bool operator() (const std::string& str) const
    {
    std::size_t f = m_word.find(str);
    return (std::string::npos!=f && m_word.length()>str.length());
    }

};

struct if_remove
{
    std::string m_word;
public:
    if_remove(const std::string& w) : m_word(w) { }

    bool operator() (std::string str) const
    {
        return m_word.length()>str.length();
    }

};


class FindLongestCompound
{

    std::ifstream m_file;

    StrSet m_words;
    std::string m_current;

public:
    FindLongestCompound(std::string filename)
    {
    m_file.open(filename, std::ifstream::in); 

    if (!m_file)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file"+filename);
    }


    void Start(void)
    {
    std::string nextWord;
    while(m_file >> nextWord)
    {

        std::cout << "read word: " << nextWord << std::endl;
        if_substr ifSubstr(nextWord);
        StrSetIter srchItem = std::find_if(std::begin(m_words), std::end(m_words),ifSubstr);
        if (srchItem != m_words.end())
        {
        m_current = nextWord; 
        std::cout << "new current: " << m_current << std::endl;


        if_remove ifRemove(m_current);
        std::remove_if(m_words.begin(), m_words.end(),ifRemove);

        #if 0
        StrSetIter j = m_words.begin();
        do 
        {
            if (j->length() < m_current.length()) 
            j = m_words.erase(j);
            else 
            j++;

        } while (j != m_words.end());
        #endif
        } 
        std::cout << "insert next word: " << nextWord << std::endl;
        m_words.insert(nextWord);
    } 
    }

    std::string result() { return m_current; } 

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc<2)
    {
    std::cout << "Please provide filename" << std::endl;
    return -1;
    }

    FindLongestCompound flc(argv[1]);

    flc.Start();

    std::cout << "result: " << flc.result() << std::endl;
}
```

> ```
> --- errors ---
> In file included from stackoverflow.C:2:
> In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
> In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
> In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
> In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2148:26:
> error: no viable overloaded '='
>                     *__first = _VSTD::move(*__i);
>                     ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     stackoverflow.C:91:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
> 'std::__1::remove_if<std::__1::__tree_const_iterator<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
> std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char>, void *> *, long>,
> if_remove>' requested here
>                     std::remove_if(m_words.begin(), m_words.end(),ifRemove);
>                          ^
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1415:19:
> note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
> value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>'), but method is
> not marked const
>         basic_string& operator=(const basic_string& __str);
>                       ^
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1422:45:
> note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
> value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>'), but method is
> not marked const
>         _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY basic_string& operator=(const value_type* __s) {return assign(__s);}
>                                                 ^
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1423:19:
> note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
> value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>'), but method is
> not marked const
>         basic_string& operator=(value_type __c);
>                       ^
>     1 error generated.
> ```

Comment: Narrow your problem down.

Comment: Please try to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, if you're programming with C++11, why are you using functor objects instead of lambdas?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yep learning STL its been painful but the people up here are awesome.

Comment: @TomOrsi: "STL"-style programming has a lot of initially hidden merits. For example, the erase-remove idiom you've stumbled upon here may first strike you as cumbersome, but the fact that "removed" elements don't necessarily have to removed makes more sense when you consider that algorithms always take two iterators and that the second one doesn't always have to be the `end()` of a container.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not with your functor but with the container type you're using. You cannot use `std::remove_if` with a `std::set` (your `StrSet` in this case).

Put simply, `std::remove_if` does not remove anything but just **changes the order of elements** such that the "removed" elements only appear after a certain point. Only `erase` really eliminates them.

A `std::set`, however, has a **defined element order** which cannot be bypassed by any operation. Let's say you have the following set of lexicographically ordered strings:

```
{ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" }
```

Now you try to apply `std::remove_if` with a functor that removes all vowel-only strings. You would end up with this:

```
{ "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "aaa", "eee" }
                     ^
                     |
        "removed" elements start here
```

This works with e.g. `std::vector` but not with `std::set` because it would result in a set whose elements are no longer ordered correctly (the "removed" elements are still part of the set!). So you get a compilation error.

In order to achieve your desired goal, use [`std::set::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) in a loop. It will work fine because only iterators to the erased element are invalidated, so `end()` remains valid.

```
if_remove ifRemove(m_current);
for (StrSet::iterator set_iter = m_words.begin(); set_iter != m_words.end(); )
{
    if (ifRemove(*set_iter))
    {
        set_iter = m_words.erase(set_iter);
    }
    else
    {
        ++set_iter;
    }
}
```

In C++11, you could use `auto` instead of `StrSet::iterator`.